Are Python 3's IOError and FileNotFoundError interchangeable?
import io
import sys
import errno



try:
    stream = open("non_existent_file", "rb")
    print("exists")
    stream.close()
except IOError as error2:
    if error2.errno == errno.ENOENT:
        print("absent2")
    else:
        print("unknown")
except FileNotFoundError as error:
    if error.errno == errno.ENOENT:
        print("absent1")
    else:
        print("unknown")

When I switch the two except/catch blocks, it ignores the re-ordering and exception always falls into the first except block. Are both exceptions interchangeable? I even printed the bases of both classes and they appear different...

IOError is an alias for OSError.  These used to be separate classes, but they were combined in Python 3.3 due to their confusing similarity.
FileNotFoundError is a subclass of OSError (aka IOError).  This lets you do:

try:
    stream = open("non_existent_file", "rb")
    print("exists")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("absent")
except IOError: # or equivalently, OSError
    print("exists, but can't be opened")

Note that you have to catch the more specific exception type first.
